# Fluid Div under fixed height elements in css?

Tags: css

I was wondering if there was a way to have an element stretch itself with the remaining window space it has when a fixed width has taken up a certain amount of the window.

For example

```
    <div id ="first">
   This div will ALWAYS be fixed at 20px height
   </div>
   <div id="second">
      This div will take up 100% of the remaining space between the top div (first div that is 20px high ) and the bottom of the window. 
     </div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using [fixed positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4Vm/):

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#first {
    height:20px;
    background:yellow;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#second {
    padding-top:20px;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And one using [relative positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4Vm/1/):

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#first {
    height:20px;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#second {
    margin-top:-20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Both are assuming the following HTML:

```
<div id ="first">
   This div will ALWAYS be fixed at 20px height
</div>
<div id="second">
   This div will take up 100% of the remaining space between the top div (first div that is 20px high ) and the bottom of the window.
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution. I just don't dare to use the border-box, as it is not compatible with older (IE) browsers

Comment: @PeterVR - Here are versions without `box-sizing`: [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4Vm/3/), [relative](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4Vm/4/)

Comment: in your fixed the header remains visble when the contents grows: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4Vm/5/ The absolute one, or relative if you want, is a nice solution though!

Answer (score 2):

If you borrow the sticky footer idea from [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), and you adapt it to get a fixed header, it would look like [this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/xLe3T/4/).

the html:

```
    <div id ="first">
   This div will ALWAYS be fixed at 20px height

</div>
   <div id="second">
       <div id="push"></div>
      This div will take up 100% of the remaining space between the top div (first div that is 20px high ) and the bottom of the window. 
     </div>​
```

the css:

```
   #first {
  height: 20px; 

}
#push {
  height: 20px; 
  background: #fcc;  
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#second {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -20px 0;
    background: #cfc;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly in Chrome/Firefox. There is a 20px overflow past the bottom of the viewport (see my comment to MrDCGN below).

Comment: @Moses, you are absolutly right, I had been fiddleing and pasted the wrong version. Corrected the fiddle and will update my post. AS you can see, it is possible and should be fully cross browser.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/xvnCd/

In your first sentence you say "fixed width" but in the code you say height, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Note that this version will lose you 20px at the bottom of the viewport, so it may or may not work for you depending on how you need this to be used.

Comment: This will not work because height:100% sets the div's height equal to 100% of the containing element. Since the containing element is the body/html, which are also 100% that means you are effectively setting the div to the same size as the viewport. This is why there is a 20px overflow at the bottom of the page... because you have a 20px div + a viewport height div.

Comment: @MrDCGN sorry but that update is just quick and dirty. Updated again to show you why, halve the content becomes unreachable if your screen size is to low... http://jsfiddle.net/xvnCd/1/

Comment: All the edit did was erase the overflowing content. This layout would be broken frequently by either the content (if it were large enough) or the browser window (if it were small enough). In other words, this doesn't scale well.